# Quotient field of a localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I have a basic question about rings of fractions.

Let $R$ be a commutative integral domain with quotient field $K$, $\mathfrak p$ a non-zero prime ideal of $R$ and $R_{\mathfrak p}$ the localization of $R$ at $\mathfrak p$.

> Is it true that $K$ is also the quotient field of $R_{\mathfrak p}$? If so how I show this?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: If by “quotient field” you mean the total ring of fractions, it is true, and you show it simply by writing down what the elements of each turn out to be.

Comment: It might be useful that the fraction field the localization at the zero prime ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ The universal mapping property of localizations (or fraction fields) yields an easy test for isomorphism, see the Corollary below, from Atiyah & MacDonald, *Commutative Algebra*, p. 39.

[image]
[image]