# What can be said about the relationship of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and the localization $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$?

Tags: ring-theory, localization

$p$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ , then $(p)$ is a prime ideal, What can be said about the relationship of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and the localization $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$? ( This question is from 'Hungerford' Algebra book )

My trial : 
Any integer $n$ that is not divisible by $p$ has a unique inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ ( what does this mean? ) . 
Then ( and why is this a consequence? ) by the universal property of the localization, there is a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Recall that the localization $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is just the fractions ring $\{\frac{a}{b}:\ a, b\in \mathbb{Z}\ and\ b\neq 0 \ and \ p\nmid b\}$

Does this answer the question ? But what homomorphism is that ? Do we need to explicitly describe it ?

Comment: hi Omar; can you clarify what your question is? at the moment it's not entirely clear what is Hungerford's writing and what is yours

Comment: What is $\Bbb{Z}_p$, the p-adic integers or the finite field?

Comment: the question is : " $p$ is a prime in $Z$ , then $(p)$ is a prime ideal, what can be said about the relationship of $Z_p$ and the localization $Z_{(p)}$? "

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: @reuns $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is just the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ of integers mod $p$

Comment: Yes, that argument using the [universal property of localization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/738809/242) is likely what was intended. As the linked proof shows, the canonical map is $\,h(a/s) = g(a)g(s)^{-1}\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ you mean $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$:

That any $n$ not divisible by $p$ has a unique inverse in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ means that  since $n$ is coprime to $p$ by Bezout's identity there exist integers $r,s$ such that
$$1=nr+ps.$$
Therefore $1\equiv nr\pmod{p}$, so $r$ is an inverse of $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (check that $r$ is in a unique coset of $p\mathbb{Z}$). Denote $n^{-1}:=r$, then the homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is given by
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}&\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\\\\
\frac{a}{b}&\mapsto ab^{-1}
\end{align}
$$
where $b^{-1}$ is well-defined because $p$ does not divide $b$.

If by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ you mean $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (the ring of $p$-adic integers):

You can identify elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as formal power series in $p$ with coefficients in $\{0,\dots,p-1\}$, so if $p$ does not divide an element $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ then
$$x=a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+\dots$$
with $a_0\neq 0$ and one can find an inverse for $x$ as a formal power series in $p$. Gathering terms of the formal inverse $x^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_np^n$ you can ensure that $b_n\in\{0,\dots,p-1\}$. So again we have an analogous homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Embedding $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ you can actually check that $\mathbb{Z}_p\cap\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.

Comment: Thank you, I also read that in general there is always a homomorphism $r/s \mapsto f(r)f(s)^{-1}$ whenever $f$ is a homomorphism (provided $f(s)\in $ the units of the codomain), well, can you maybe also tell me why is this useful? I mean where is this going to? I have to admit my professor isn't giving a sense to any of this.

Comment: @Omar Yes you can define a similar homomorphism as long as $f(s)$ is be invertible for $s$ in your multiplicatively closed set. In your case this set is $\mathbb{Z}-p\mathbb{Z}$. It is useful as long as it helps you understand the idea better. We didn't need to use the particular structure of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ extensively. We just had to show that the right elements would be invertible.

Comment: @Omar If you were wondering why is useful to see that the localisation has that homomorphism. It is a general theme in category theory and algebra to express things in terms of universal properties. I believe this is because it makes things cleaner and simplifies proofs. For example: You can define your localisation (as a set) in any way you want, and by showing that the universal property is satisfied you will know that it is unique up to isomorphism, so any other construction that satisfies that universal property should be isomorphic. In a way it helps you get other results "for free".

Comment: well so far we are not getting any results, it would be useful to include such results in such an algebra course, at least including also the historical motivations, as much as I see how groups are useful and it is important to list them all, I don't have the same enthusiasm about rings. They seem just boring.